# Mount docker VM file

Tags: docker

On my mac laptop running mac os Ventura, Docker VM data is in the Docker.raw file:

```
$ ls -al ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/vms/0/data/

-rw-r--r--@ 1 user  staff  127999672320 Aug 22 00:02 Docker.raw
```

Can I mount the Docker.raw file so that I can inspect its contents?

```
$ file ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/vms/0/data/Docker.raw

DOS/MBR boot sector; partition 1 : ID=0x83, active, start-CHS (0x1,0,1), end-CHS (0x3ff,63,32), startsector 2048, 249997312 sectors
```

Here are the contents of the partition table:

```
$ fdisk -d ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/vms/0/data/Docker.raw

2048,249997312,0x83,*,1,0,1,1023,63,32
0,0,0x00,-,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0x00,-,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0x00,-,0,0,0,0,0,0

$ fdisk -l ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/vms/0/data/Docker.raw

fdisk: illegal option -- l
usage: fdisk [-ieu] [-f mbrboot] [-c cyl -h head -s sect] [-S size] [-r] [-a style] disk
        -i: initialize disk with new MBR
        -u: update MBR code, preserve partition table
        -e: edit MBRs on disk interactively
        -f: specify non-standard MBR template
        -chs: specify disk geometry
        -S: specify disk size
        -r: read partition specs from stdin (implies -i)
        -a: auto-partition with the given style
        -d: dump partition table
        -y: don't ask any questions
        -t: test if disk is partitioned
`disk' is of the form /dev/rdisk0.
auto-partition styles:
  boothfs     8Mb boot plus HFS+ root partition (default)
  hfs         Entire disk as one HFS+ partition
  dos         Entire disk as one DOS partition
  raid        Entire disk as one 0xAC partition
```

Thanks.

Comment: I believe that's some proprietary VM image, which includes MBR, etc..

Comment: What does `file Docker.raw` say, also `fdisk -l Docker.raw`? (As a reminder, you have to put the requested information [into the question](https://serverfault.com/posts/1142078/edit).)

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov, I updated my question with the requested info.

Comment: Well, it does contain MBR from which we see it's a hard disk image with a single partition of type 0x83 = Linux filesystem. I don't know how to mount in in macOS, sorry, I overlooked that part. In Linux I'd use a loop device with offset=1048576 sizelimit=127998623744 (those numbers are 2048 * 512 and 249997312 * 512, respectively) for that.